# positive definite matrix as a function of polynomails

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Given polynomials functions as ${f_i}\left( x \right) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^N {{a_j}{x^j}}$, how can I prove that the following matrix is positive definite or not?
$${\bf{A}} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{f_1^2\left( x \right)}&{{f_1}\left( x \right){f_2}\left( x \right)}& \cdots &{{f_1}\left( x \right){f_N}\left( x \right)}\\
{{f_2}\left( x \right){f_1}\left( x \right)}&{f_2^2\left( x \right)}& \cdots &{{f_2}\left( x \right){f_N}\left( x \right)}\\
 \vdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{{f_N}\left( x \right){f_1}\left( x \right)}&{{f_N}\left( x \right){f_2}\left( x \right)}& \cdots &{f_N^2\left( x \right)}
\end{array}} \right]$$

Answer (score 1):

This is a rank-one symmetric matrix. It will be positive semidefinite (but not positive definite for $N>1$) if and only if its trace is non-negative.

If these are real polynomials, then the matrix will always be positive semidefinite.

Comment: note that the answer, and the reason for it, become completely different if we switch to $a_{ij} = \langle f_i, f_j \rangle,$ where, for example, $$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x) dx $$ I bring it up because that is what I first assumed was there....